# using jquery ajax response to make an option selected not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code wherein my `Jquery` would fetch the data within the page inside a `select` inside a `table`. I am now familiar with how to use `AJAX` responses and `Jquery`. But this time, it seems like something is wrong within the `Jquery` itself.

Here's my `AJAX` Response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../api/ajax/getInventory.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        // console.log(response["data"]);
        // console.log(Object.keys(response["data"][0]).length);
        for (var i = 0; i < response["data"].length; i++) {
            $("select#ingredient_1").append('<option value="'+response['data'][i][0]+'">'+response['data'][i][1]+'</option>');
        }
    }
});

var id = "<?php echo $id ?>";
$.ajax({
    url: "../api/ajax/getProductIngredient.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(response){
        // console.log(response);
        $('#ingredient_1 option[value="'+response[0].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);
        $("#amount_unit_1").text(response[0].amount_unit);
        $('#amount_1').val(response[0].amount);
        for (var i = 1; i < Object.keys(response).length; i++) {
            // console.log(response[i]);
            var table = $("#ingredients_info_table");
            var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr").length;
            var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));

            var html = '<tr id="row_'+row_id+'"><td><select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_'+row_id+'" id="ingredient_'+row_id+'" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount(\''+row_id+'\')" style="width:100%;" required><option value=""selected disabled hidden></option>'
            html += '</select>'+'</td><td><label for="amount"><i id="amount_unit_'+row_id+'" >Amount Unit</i> x</label><input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" required style="display: inline-block;"></td>'+
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeRow(\''+row_id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>'+
            '</tr>';

            $.ajax({
                url: "../api/ajax/getInventory.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response2){
                    // console.log(response2["data"]);
                    // console.log(Object.keys(response2["data"][0]).length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < response2["data"].length; i++) {
                        $("select#ingredient_"+row_id).append('<option value="'+response2['data'][i][0]+'">'+response2['data'][i][1]+'</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
            if(count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
                $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr:last").after(html);
                // console.log(1);
            }
            else {
                $("#ingredients_info_table tbody").html(html);
                // console.log(2);
            }

            console.log($('#ingredient_'+row_id).children("option:selected"). val());
            // console.log($('#ingredient_'+row_id));
            console.log(row_id);
            console.log(response[i].ingredient_id);
            $('#ingredient_'+row_id+' option[value="'+response[i].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);
            console.log($('#ingredient_'+row_id).children("option:selected"). val());
            $('#amount_unit_'+row_id).text(response[i].amount_unit);
            $('#amount_'+row_id).val(response[i].amount);

        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

As mentioned from the comments of the code, the part of the code wherein my `Jquery` is used to make an option generated from an `AJAX` response doesn't work. My guess is that the generated `rows of data` from the `Jquery` is not reading the `$('#ingredient_'+row_id+' option[value="'+response[i].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);`

Send help.

EDIT: Here's the `div` with table

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <label for="item_name">Product Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="counter" id="counter" style="margin-left:90%;" size="3" maxlength="3" value="160" readonly>
        <textarea name="mname" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="80" style="resize:none;" id="text" placeholder="Type" onKeyDown = "countText(document.getElementById('text'),document.getElementById('counter'),160)"
        onKeyUp = "countText(document.getElementById('text'),document.getElementById('counter'),160)" maxlength="160"><?php echo $mname ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="ingredients_info_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:60%">Ingredients</th>
                    <th style="width:30%">Amount</th>
                    <th style="width:10%">
                        <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="row_1">
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_1" id="ingredient_1" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount(1)" style="width:100%;" required>
                            <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="amount"><i id="amount_unit_1" >Amount Unit</i> x</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" class="form-control" required style="display: inline-block;"  >
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the logs

```
product-update.php?id=67:436 
product-update.php?id=67:438 285
product-update.php?id=67:439 1573065076
product-update.php?id=67:441
```

EDIT: here's the updated `options` after the `AJAX` responses

```
<select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_639" id="ingredient_639" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount('639')" style="width:100%;" required="">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden=""></option><option value="12">sugar
    </option>
    <option value="1573065076">Iceice beybe
    </option>
    <option value="1573266969">try
    </option>
</select>
```

the data that needs to be compared is `console.log(response[i].ingredient_id);` which is equal to `1573065076` which appears on the 2nd `option` of the updated `select options`.

Comment: add `error` calback also. is there any error?

Comment: @Kaushik upon adding `error: function()`, nope. there is no error on my `AJAX`

Comment: Have you checked that the `response[i].ingredient_id` value matches something in the DOM?

Comment: is there any error in console? add your html also and the JSON log.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've been comparing the value of the `response[i].ingredient_id` on my DOM. I've been checking if there's a hidden space or anything. 

Yes, there's a matching value.

Comment: @Kaushik none. . . .

Answer (score 2):

You are appending more options to the select box using another ajax call and before completing that you are trying to make options selected which will not work.

Move option selection script inside ajax call, see below

```
    var id = "<?php echo $id ?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "../api/ajax/getProductIngredient.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function(response){
            // console.log(response);

            $('#ingredient_1 option[value="'+response[0].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);
            $("#amount_unit_1").text(response[0].amount_unit);
            $('#amount_1').val(response[0].amount);
            for (var i = 1; i < Object.keys(response).length; i++) {
                var table = $("#ingredients_info_table");
                var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr").length;
                var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));

                var html = '<tr id="row_'+row_id+'"><td><select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_'+row_id+'" id="ingredient_'+row_id+'" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount(\''+row_id+'\')" style="width:100%;" required><option value=""selected disabled hidden></option>'
                html += '</select>'+'</td><td><label for="amount"><i id="amount_unit_'+row_id+'" >Amount Unit</i> x</label><input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" required style="display: inline-block;"></td>'+
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeRow(\''+row_id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>'+
                '</tr>';

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../api/ajax/getInventory.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response2){
                        for (var i = 0; i < response2["data"].length; i++) {
                            $("select#ingredient_"+row_id).append('<option value="'+response2['data'][i][0]+'">'+response2['data'][i][1]+'</option>');
                        }
//make selection of option here
                        $('#ingredient_'+row_id+' option[value="'+response[i].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);
                    }
                });
                if(count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
                    $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr:last").after(html);
                }
                else {
                    $("#ingredients_info_table tbody").html(html);
                }

                //the next line of code doesn't work. 
                //$('#ingredient_'+row_id+' option[value="'+response[i].ingredient_id+'"]').attr("selected", true);
                //but this one works just fine.
                $('#amount_unit_'+row_id).text(response[i].amount_unit);
                $('#amount_'+row_id).val(response[i].amount);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'll try it now.

Comment: nope, no errors after including an ```error: function()```

Comment: can you update the HTML code with updated options after AJAX call and see if it matches `response[i].ingredient_id` bcoz putting selected attribute code is pretty simple. It would be good if you can reproduce this issue on jsfiddle and share the link with me so that i can take a look at it

Comment: I've now updated the HTML code. I'll try to make a jsfiddle version of it.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zok5cpmn/)
this is my first time using jsfiddle. I don't kow how to make a sample data output using this